# Running a .NET solution file in Linux without Admin rights

Tags: c#, .net, linux, visual-studio, solution

*Note : I don't have root permission in my Linux box.*

I need to compile a .NET (visual studio executable) solution file in my Linux machine.
I have just heard about a way that Microsoft is providing an extension to perform the same like mono, Yocto, etc.,

What are the possible ways that i can run the solution? 
Can someone please tel me how do i do it?

Comment: You can't compile a piece of C# code in Linux. As far as I know, C# works only in the Windows environment

Comment: Have a look at the below site.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/xbuild

Comment: There are some ways we can achieve it. But I need the best way to do it.

Comment: I dont think xbuild necessarily runs or compiles the MSbuild file.

Comment: I don't think Microsoft will undercut its expensive Visual Studio to create free tools for Linux.  It's just open source the .NET Core Library to help [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/). This way it makes C# developers a little more valuable.

Comment: Thanks Black Frog and ryekayo ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the .NET framework has been made open source, but there is not official release **yet** for Linux.  The development community for Linux would be the one most likely to make the tools.

Excerpt from Microsoft Site: [.NET Core is Open Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/11/12/net-core-is-open-source.aspx)

> Today (Nov. 12, 2014) is a huge day for .NET! We’re happy to announce
>   that [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) will be open source, including the runtime as well as
>   the framework libraries.
>
> This is a natural progression of our open source efforts, which
>   already covers the managed compilers (C#, VB, and F#) as well as
>   ASP.NET:
>
> - C# & Visual Basic ("Roslyn")
> - Visual F# Tools
> - ASP.NET 5
> - Entity Framework
>
> This takes it to the next level by extending it to the .NET runtime
>   and the core framework.

Comment: Oh it means that we cannot perform MSBuild operations from Linux environment now?

Comment: If there are any option for doing so, please let me know. It would help me anytime.